# how do I assign value across whole array with foor loop

Tags: arrays

Why doesn't this work ie assign each element in the array to 1?

```
         int []iA2 = new int[10];
         System.out.println(iA2[0]); //0
         for (int place:iA2){
             place=1;
         }
         System.out.println(iA2[1]); // prints 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The values from iA2 are being assigned to variable `place`. You then modify the value of `place`.
What you should do:

```
for (int i=0; i<iA2.length; i++)
    iA2[i] = 1;
```

Note that if you were dealing with objects such as an instance of a Vehicle class you could iterate and change instance variables.

```
for (Vehicle v: vehicles)
    v.speed = 10;
```

This works because `v` is being assigned a reference to an object unlike what happens in the case of primitive types such as int.